# I want to control a my GSM phone using a Mac and Bluetooth

Tags: mac, bluetooth

I have a Nokia 6600. I want to see incoming calls, messages on my Mac using Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Blue Phone Elite](http://mirasoftware.com/BPE2/).  Works well with a Nokia e65.  It's not free, but worth the money (i feel).

This allows you to send and recieve SMS messages on your Mac and also use it as a bluetooth headset.

I have just checked the compatibility list, and does not let you send SMS messages due to a limitation of the device.  Not sure what this is.

Comment: Awesome... im gonna buy it for sure

Comment: I think they have a free trial for 15 days or something

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apples built-in iSync, which would be free: http://europe.nokia.com/get-support-and-software/download-software/isync

If you'd like to control your mac with your phone (play music, video, start screensaver when you leave, start music when you come back etc.) I'd try Salling Clicker: http://www.salling.com/Clicker/mac/

Hope it helps. :-)